# Rollapply breaks and start again in R?

Tags: r, rollapply

I have a data frame which looks like

```
z<-data.frame(a=c(seq(1990,1995,1), 1997,1998,1999,2001,2002,2003), b=seq(90,101,1))
```

I use function

```
rollapply(b, 3, sd, align='right')
```

to calculate standard deviation.

The thing I want to do is that function breaks and starts to calculate standard deviation
again if there is a gap between consecutive years.

EDIT:

My sample output should look like this:

```
enter code here       a   b    c
                 1  1990  90  NA
                 2  1991  91  NA
                 3  1992  92  sd(90,91,92)
                 4  1993  93  sd(93,92,91)
                 5  1994  94  sd(94,93,92)
                 6  1995  95  sd(95,94,93)
                 7  1997  96  NA
                 8  1998  97  NA
                 9  1999  98  sd(98,97,96)
                10  2001  99  NA
                11  2002  100 NA
                12  2003  101 sd(101,100,99)
```

Comment: Can you show sample output ? It's hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @:Jdbaba. Thank you for attention. I have added.

Comment: I presume by `sd(c(90,91,92))` you mean the result of running `sd(c(90,91,92))`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
my.roll <- function(x) rollapply(x, 3, sd, align='right', fill=NA, na.rm=T)
z$sd <- ave(z$b, c(0, cumsum(diff(z$a) - 1)), FUN=my.roll)
```

Produces:

```
      a   b sd
1  1990  90 NA
2  1991  91 NA
3  1992  92  1
4  1993  93  1
5  1994  94  1
6  1995  95  1
7  1997  96 NA
8  1998  97 NA
9  1999  98  1
10 2001  99 NA
11 2002 100 NA
12 2003 101  1
```

Note how the first two entries after each gap are NA because you need at least three values in your window.

Basically, what we do here is use `cumsum` and `diff` to figure out the blocks of contiguous years, and then with that we can use `ave` to apply `sd` to each block.  Note this will break if you have repeated years (e.g. 1997 shows up 2 or more times), or if your data isn't sorted by year.

Answer (score 1):

Convert data.frame to a zoo object, `z`, and merge that with a grid, `g`, of all years including the ones not found in `z`.  Apply `rollapplyr` to that and extract out the original times:

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = identity)
g <- merge(z, zoo(, start(z):end(z)))
r <- rollapplyr(g, 3, sd, fill = NA)[I(time(z))]
```

giving:

```
> r
1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1997 1998 1999 2001 2002 2003 
  NA   NA    1    1    1    1   NA   NA    1   NA   NA    1
```

`r` is a zoo object for which `time(r)` is the times and `coredata(r)` is the data.

*Note:* We have used:

```
DF <- structure(list(V1 = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 
  1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L), V2 = 90:101), .Names = c("V1", 
  "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: I must have pasted the wrong output.  I have now run it again and pasted the correct output in.  The code is unchanged.